# How can i change a curve to have the same proportions on all its vertices?

Tags: modeling, animation, bezier-curves

i made a curve as you can see in the image, but i need to take a part of the curve (for example, ten vertices) and make all the curve look like that part, is that possible? i need to do this because i need to animate it in another layer, as a continuous curve with loop.

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify what you want the same? bevel depth?

Comment: The distance between the vertices/curves

Comment: Wait, you want to straighten it out again so the curves are completely congruent throughout the entire length?

Comment: I edited the image, that's what i'm trying to do :/

Comment: Yes, i need the curves to be the same over and over alongside the length.

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20242/discussion-between-noviceindisguise-and-beavoru).

Comment: Is it possible to give a single proportion on all the curve/lenght?

Comment: Consider an array modifier maybe . . . select the good vertices, and press `Shift`+`D` and then *`P` > By Selection* then add an *Array* modifier to that. After tha, apply it (be sure to enable *Merge* in the modifier settings).

Comment: This is **so** unclear of what you are asking. Does the first curve have variable frequency or is it half a circle from the sideview? Do you need the result curve to have constant frequency or variable one but repeated? Why don't you create the curve like you want in the first place? etc. etc.

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise i got able to fix it with your method :)

Comment: Excellent! I guess I'll write it as an answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, select the good vertices in edit mode (at least three, one whole waveform):

[image]

Then press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and then <kbd>P</kbd> to separate the new vertices into a new curve:

[image]

Now add an *Array* modifier to the new curve, making sure to tick the *Merge* checkbox:

[image]

You should now have something like this:

[image]

Notice that the fewer waveforms you select initially the more accurate the result will be, although it will take vastly more repeats on the *Array* modifier. It is however completely adjustable at that point, so it can be given the exact same number of waveforms as your other curve.

Once you are happy with the result, change the handles to vector, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and convert to mesh, then the same and convert back to a curve, and change the handle type back to whatever it was. You should now have one continuous curve. The reason you need to do this is because you are not allowed to apply a constructive modifier on a curve.